# I cannot install or remove any packages because I keep getting this error: subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127

Tags: package-management

I installed a cups wrapper for a printer, but it's broken. Now both the Store and Synaptic won't install or remove any packages because the "mfc240ccupswrapper" cannot be repaired or changed. I've tried to force remove it to no avail.

This is the output of attempting to remove the package:

```
Removing mfc240ccupswrapper ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mfc240ccupswrapper.prerm: 3: /usr/local/Brother/Printer/mfc240c/cupswrapper/cupswrappermfc240c: not found
dpkg: error processing mfc240ccupswrapper (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mfc240ccupswrapper.postinst: 3: /usr/local/Brother/Printer/mfc240c/cupswrapper/cupswrappermfc240c: not found
chmod: cannot access `/usr/local/Brother/Printer/mfc240c/cupswrapper': No such file or directory
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mfc240ccupswrapper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after trying several commands in the terminal to try to force remove it, I finally was able to figure out that the package had not completely installed. So I opened the DEB file, copied the rest of the files, and using "gksudo nautilus" to gain root access, I pasted the rest of the files which included the folder that the error mentioned was missing. Then Synaptic was able to fix the package, and I was able to permanently remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this    `dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mfc240ccupswrapper`

Comment: I did try that and it still wouldn't remove. I had to do what I answered below in order for the package to be fixed so that I could remove it. Thanks for the response though!